# SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) returns false on identity scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

using default code for Identity in Blazor I have seen that by using authentication cookies the user isn't set as logged, while the cookie exist in the browser and the link/action to be signed out wasn't callled

What could I possibly need to check what would be causing this behavior?

the only line of code I had used is a js code to call automatically the signout action on post which only exist in the logout view(which is only called in the lougout link, but for example calling the login page shows as if it wasnt logged in(which is checked at the loging partial view

````
<script>
   
    (() =>
    {
        document.getElementById('logoutFormLocal').submit();
    })();
</script>```

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/Index", new { area = "" })">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
````

Comment: Hi @PontiacGTX, if you use Blazor, it will default use AuthorizeView component to  achieve authorize instead of by using your code. Your code is used in asp.net core mvc or razor pages when use Identity.

Comment: @Rena I am but the Identity Scaffolding creates the identity login and cookies authentication but somehow it doesnt work